# :scope pseudo-selector in MS Edge

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, selectors-api

Whenever I use `querySelectorAll` in Microsoft Edge with the `:scope` pseudo-selector, this error appears in the console

> SCRIPT5022: SCRIPT5022: SyntaxError

I was wondering if there was an alternative to `querySelectorAll`, where I use this parameter: `:scope > * > table`. I do not want to use jQuery for this. Thanks.

## EDIT:

I also wanted to add that `querySelector` works by itself

Okay, here is the code sample:

```
            function pJSON(panel) {
                var json = {tables: [], images: [], text: ""};
                var tables = Array.from(panel.querySelectorAll(":scope > * > table"));
                var images = Array.from(panel.querySelectorAll(":scope > * > img"));
                var text = panel.querySelector(":scope > textarea");
                tables.forEach(table => {
                    json["tables"].push(tJSON(table));
                });
                images.forEach(image => {
                    json["images"].push(image.outerHTML);
                });
                if (text) {
                    json["text"] = text.value;
                }
                return json;
            }
```

I will note again that it works in all browsers except IE and Microsoft Edge

Oh, and an example of some HTML that might be dynamically added, this is the code that was there when I called this method:

```
<div>
    <input type="file" multiple=""><br>
    <button>Add Table</button><br>
    <div>
        <table style="display: inline-table;">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="file" multiple=""><br>
                        <button>Add Table</button><br>
                        <textarea placeholder="Write some text"></textarea>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="file" multiple=""><br>
                        <button>Add Table</button><br>
                        <textarea placeholder="Write some text"></textarea>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button style="margin-left: 100px;">x</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="file" multiple=""><br>
                        <button>Add Table</button><br>
                        <textarea placeholder="Write some text"></textarea>  
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="file" multiple=""><br>
                        <button>Add Table</button><br>
                        <textarea placeholder="Write some text"></textarea>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button style="margin-left: 100px;">x</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <button style="margin-left: 100px;">x</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Ele my code goes like this: `var tables = Array.from(panel.querySelectorAll(":scope > * > table"));`

Comment: The other alternative is element.query/queryAll. These are alternative methods to querySelector and querySelectorAll that exist on DOM parent nodes. They also take selectors, except these selectors are interpreted relative to the element being queried from. Reference: https://developer.rackspace.com/blog/using-querySelector-on-elements/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So what you are after is actually a polyfill for `:scope`.

There is one available at https://github.com/jonathantneal/element-qsa-scope

How it works is basically to first define a unique enough selector on the element to be matched and prepend it to the selector passed to querySelector.

```js
const li = document.getElementById('target');
console.log('no :scope', li.querySelector('li>a')) // Link

// workaround
const UUID = Date.now()+'';
li.setAttribute('data-scope-uuid', UUID);
console.log('workedaround', li.querySelector('[data-scope-uuid="'+UUID+'"] li>a'));
li.removeAttribute('data-scope-UUID');

// where supported
console.log(':scope', li.querySelector(':scope li>a'));
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="target"><a>Link</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a>Sublink</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And to test for native support, you can simply wrap a `document.querySelector(':scope') === document.documentElement` in a try catch block.